# Cannot find symbol error in Java with args[]

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am a beginner in Java.
I am trying to write a program that takes two numbers and a string as a command line argument and it prints out the substring specified by the two numbers.

For example:

> % java Substring hello 1 3

output:

> ell

This is my code inside main:

```
  String a = args[1];
  String b = args[2];
  String d = args[0];
  String c = d.subString(a, b);
  System.out.println(c);
```

The compiler gives me an error saying:

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol:   method subString(String,String)
>
> location: variable d of type String

Comment: It's `substring` (and param types are not correct).

Comment: Furthermore, there is no substring method that accepts two Strings as parameters.

Comment: And it doesn't take Strings, but ints as arguments. Why don't you read the javadoc, which lists all the methods available on all classes and describes them? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: cast args[2] and args[1] to integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `subString` but [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). Java is **case-sensitive** language. Besides, the `substring` method takes in 2 `int`eger arguments so your code will definitely not compile.

You're passing integer values so the correct way should be to parse a `String` to `int` using [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) function.

```
 int a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //The beginIndex (starting from 0, inclusive)
 int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); //The endIndex (of maximum string.length(), exclusive).
 String d = args[0];
 String c = d.subString(a, b);
 System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `substring()` not `subString()`. Syntax incorrect. Also `substring()` accept `int` argument not `String` arguments.

Use

```
int a=1;// starting index
int b=5;// ending index
String c = d.substring(a, b); // here a and b must be int values
```

Instead of

```
String c = d.subString(a, b);
```

[substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) in `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

1.) `subString` should be written as `substring`

2.) Also method `substring` accepts `int arguments`

**Inside Definition of substring method**

```
  public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
```

`a and b` should be of `int type` instead of `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

You are calling it wrong, the method takes one or two integer